# How to read a Hyper link value in excel sheet..?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, datagrid, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am importing data from excel file to flex grid but my excel file has some hyper links and when i read the cell value it gives me the text displayed in that cell not the actual path of the link. i am using as3xls library.

Comment: you want to display the hyper link as text or the as a hyperlink control?

Comment: yes as a text. my only concern is that i want to display the value. eg: if my cell hyperlink text is "test" and the hyperlink value is    "file///c:temp/abc.xls" then i want the value not the text displayed in cell "test".